# NPM - Error: Cannot find module '../'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm reading [this](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie) doc on `hapi-auth-cookie` and trying to run sample server.here is what i did :

1-putting sample server in server.js

2-npm init

3-node server.js

4-npm install --save hapi

5-node server.js but this time i get a new error

**Error: Cannot find module '../'**

somewhere in the code it's requiring **'../'**

```
server.register(require('../'), (err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
```

But i don't understand this part really.you can see the full code in the link above.what should i do? thanks

Comment: Looking at the link you posted, the index.js file of that module is in the /lib directory and usually you want to import a module by name in the npm construct

Comment: i think you are right and might need to post it as the answer.i will work on it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the link you posted, the index.js file of that module is in the /lib (https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie/tree/master/lib) directory and usually you want to import a module by name in the npm construct.

So put your server.js in /lib

Comment: It is possible to `require` a folder? What exactly does that? Or did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: I might be understanding as well, but in npm if you want to require hapi you'd want to write the line `var hapi = require('hapi');` instead of requiring a specific file within a module after installing.

Comment: Yea, exactly, what surprises me is the line in the example of hapi where they have that `server.register(require('../'))`. I first thought that you have to replace it with something, but that wouldnt really be an example.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error. I just deleted the node_modules directory and rerun install.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

After that the app runs correct again.

Comment: same here. any idea why that is?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there isn't a `index.js` file in directory `../`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
server.register(require('../'), (err) => {
```

with

```
server.register(require('hapi-auth-cookie'), (err) => {
```

and be sure to run

```
npm i -S hapi-auth-cookie
```

and

```
npm i -S hapi
```

before you start your server